# FTP PHP through different server

Tags: php, linux, ftp

i have a problem with FTP Function in PHP. I'm using ExtJS for Upload Form and php for processing method ,

Let me give you a view about my structure.

- A : Linux Web Server
- B : Windows Web Server
- C : Windows FTP Server

i can upload my file to C by using B
but i can't upload my file to C by using A..

here's my php script ,

```
$uploaded = 'C:/blabla/'.$file;
$remote_file = $file;

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $uploaded, FTP_ASCII)) 
            {
                $result["success"] = true;
                echo json_encode($result);  
            } 
else 
            {
                $result["failure"] = true;
                echo json_encode($result);
            }
```

this script working fine on Windows web server (result = success) , but failed on Linux web server (result = failure)

I'm sure that ftp is enable, i checked it through php_info().

looks like i can't put my file via Linux (tmp directory or anything)

any suggestion? 
thanks

ps : path of file name is needed to be initialized on ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong path for Linux $uploaded = 'C:/blabla/'.$file; It can't be C:/, you need to change it to the right path on Linux.